# Can the console in Eclipse pop up the way it does in Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse the console is embedded within the interface, but in Visual Studio it pops up whenever the code is compiled. Is there anyway to make this happen in Eclipse as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer No! 
Long answer, you can try to change the behavior a bit. As those two are totally different Tools behavior is also different.
Change the settings of console at:
Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Console

And open/close console or other views from Window->Show View